# Looking for: Future, dystopian, virus & vaccine, medical check, government agency killing people

Tags: story-identification, dystopia, virus

I'm looking for... something!  I'm honestly not sure if it's a book, radio play, TV-series or movie, but I *think* it's probably a book or radio play.

It's set in a bit of a dystopian future.  A few decades previously a terrible disease killed many people (I assume painfully and drawn-out), but eventually a vaccine was made.  To be on the safe side, people are called in for regular medical check-ups, but no more infected people have been found since.

On an unrelated note, a government agency has been set up to execute random people. I'm a bit unclear on the background here, but I assume it's because of lack of resources/food after the plague. The names of the people to be executed just pop out of a computer (or something). The story's protagonist works for this organization as a liquidator. (I don't know the term used in the book, so let's call it "liquidator.")

One of the "liquidators" is especially revered among his colleagues, because once when he got his wife's name on a kill order, he immediately went home and killed her without hesitation.  (I think it's mentioned they were happily married for many years and still loved each other.)

I'm a bit unclear how it happens, but the protagonist somehow gets suspicious and starts to investigate for some reason.  He eventually confronts the political leader or his ultimate boss, and is told the truth:

> There is no vaccine; it never worked!  The virus is still rampant and as deadly as ever!  The health checks are really there to pick out infected people in the early, non-visible stages of the disease.  The names of any infected are then sent to the termination unit, so they can be killed before the symptoms become visible.  The leader explains they had to set it up like this, to prevent widespread panic.

If I heard it as a radio play, it may have been in Norwegian...  But it's still quite likely it had been translated from an English language  play or book.

Comment: Not the answer but worth a click as a pandemic dystopia "Quarantine (1989)" https://youtu.be/IhKNZ5MAksQ

Comment: As far as surprise twists go - a termination unit actually killing people with a real deadly virus is fairly ethical.  Generally these sorts of things are just fake population control or some other devious reason.

Comment: The question made me think of the film Equilibrium, but it's only the vaguest match.

Comment: Vaguely how long ago did you ... experience this? It might help you to narrow it down if you associate this memory with some other events in your life.

Comment: "Non-visible"... What's the matter with the word "invisible"? Or, for that matter, "asymptomatic"?

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron if the original question poser is Norwegian I suspect we'd do less gooder in his language.  But perhaps you just really love the word invisible?

Comment: @lucasbachmann While reviewing manuscripts, I've found that Norwegians write better English than most native English speakers (American or British).

Answer (score -2):

This sounds a lot like "Equilibrium". It's both a book series and a movie.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you were to [edit] it to explain the ways in which it matches the story described in the question, and any ways in which it doesn't match that story.

Comment: What book is the movie Equilibrium based on?        
  I can't find out on Google